# create screen session that doesn't terminate with the program

Tags: linux, bash, session

I'm working on a startup script that is initiated from rc.local.  I start up several programs with

screen -d -m my-prog

and that works great.  However, if one of the programs has problems and exits, so does the session.  I'd like to be able to have the session stick around so I can attach to it and see the output from the program before it crashed.

Is there a way to do this?  I thought about

screen -d -m bash -c my-prog

But again, if my-prog terminates then so does bash and then so does screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the answer at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47271/prevent-gnu-screen-from-terminating-session-once-executed-script-ends

They suggest something like you were trying in your second attempt, but instead of using bash to invoke the command (which terminates with the command as you noted), invoke bash after the command finishes like:

```
screen -dmS session_name sh -c 'my-prog; exec bash'
```